# Chopping old vegetable/fruit to the ground as compost

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, compost

Sometimes I have vegetable/fruit that's gone bad and it's going to be thrown. I was thinking about chopping it and mix it with the ground of the plants I have (not so many).

Will it be helpful for the plant? What I was thinking is that I don't know how the rotting process of the vegetable/fruit will affect the plant, is it useful in the beginning of the rotting process, or only afterwards, as done with regular compost?

If it will, once in how long it will be good to add one? A few weeks?

(My plants are pretty small. They lay in pots by the window)

I leave in a small apartment so I don't have room for compost, and there's no place near me that collects it.

Comment: I would not do it: smell, flies and insects.

Comment: This Q & A here answers your query re composting in potted plants https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/28759/why-is-dumping-kitchen-waste-like-peels-of-a-potato-in-a-potted-plant-a-bad-id

Comment: @arieljannai I just added some info to the other question about worm composting as I think it's new material that would help you as an apartment dweller with little space and no take-away compost service. You can definitely compost in your apartment and use the resulting worm-castings to feed little pots in the window.